# How to add arrows to x and y axes with Veusz?

Tags: plot, veusz

How to add arrows to x and y axes with Veusz like on the image below ?
[image]

I didn't find such property in the axis widget.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very important question for me as well. The only way I could do was to insert a line (with arrow end) and overlap to the axis. For specific question related to Veusz, perhaps you can join and ask in the Veusz forum which is quite responsive and helpful. [Veusz discussion subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Veusz/)